# syntax error in mdx query mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mdx

I have been asked to direct query the cube rather than `sql` however I can't get the `mdx` query to work. I am using `adomd.net`, can someone help me! its driving me mad, below is the query i am having trouble with

```
string command = @" select
nonempty([Delivered Time].[Delivered Month Name])  on rows,
{[Recognised Time].[YSTD].[All].[TY],[Recognised Time].[YSTD].[All].[SDLY],[Recognised Time].[YSTD].[All].[FCST YTD]} on columns
from [cube]
WHERE ([Measures].[Weeks Course],strtomember("[Delivered Time].[Delivered Y-Q-M-W-D].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyy") + "]"));"
```

Syntax errors are after strtomember
    ("[Delivered Time].[Delivered Y-Q-M-W-D].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyy") + "]"))"

Comment: Well yes, you've got a double quote within your string - which is terminating the string literal... Within a verbatim string literal, use `""` to represent a single double-quote character.

Comment: Thanks Jon, it worked! ur a legend.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Jon Skeet (hopefully I've implemented ok) you need to replace all `"` with `""`:

```
string command = @" SELECT
nonempty([Delivered Time].[Delivered Month Name])  on rows,
{[Recognised Time].[YSTD].[All].[TY],[Recognised Time].[YSTD].[All].[SDLY],[Recognised Time].[YSTD].[All].[FCST YTD]} on columns
from [cube]
WHERE ([Measures].[Weeks Course],strtomember("[Delivered Time].[Delivered Y-Q-M-W-D].&["" + Format(now(), ""yyyy"") + ""]""));"
```